# Node.js: Receiving empty body when submitting form

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, curl, express

I'm aware that similar questions have been asked a lot here, but I still couldn't solve my problem. I really don't undestand whats going on.
I'm trying to send data from a form via `post` request but keep receiving an empty body.
The Jade code for the form looks like this: (**Edit:** added `enctype`)

```
    form(enctype="application/json" action="/test" method="post" name="login")
        table
            tr
                th
                    label(for="username") Username
                td
                    input(type="text" name="username" placeholder="username")
            tr
                th
                    label(for="password") Password
                td
                    input(type="password" name="password" placeholder="password")
            tr
            tr
                th
                td
                    input(type="submit" value="Login")
```

Which generates the following HTML code (**Edit:** add HTML code):

```
<form enctype="application/json" action="/test" method="post" name="login">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label for="username">Username</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
      </th>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

So I didn't forget the `name` attribute.

This is how I handle the request:

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res) {
    console.log('body:', req.body);
    res.render('login', {title: 'HK Test'});
});
```

Which prints `body {}`. So I am sure that the request is received.

I am also using bodyparser:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());`
```

However, when I use curl: `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:4000/login`, the body contains username and objects. I copied the Jade code from another working project, so I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Does anyone have an idea about what could be the reason for this?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski: Thank you, but I just pasted the code wrong. In the actual code `table` is a child of `form`. I updated the code.

Answer (score 2):

To serialize your form data to JSON when submitting, you have to add this attribute to your form:

```
enctype="application/json"
```

Otherwise, without any help from JS, your form data will not be encapsulated as a JSON for a POST request.

**Further reading:**

> [W3C JSON form submission](https://darobin.github.io/formic/specs/json/)

Comment: I also just noticed that and tried it. I updated my question above with the new code. But it is still not working :(

Answer (score -1):

You request is not /test in curl request

```
http://localhost:4000/login
```

change it to

```
http://localhost:4000/test
```

you have forgot Comma

```
    form(action="/test", method="post", name="login")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is not the problem. `http://localhost:4000/login` is the url for my form. But when submitting it, I send it to /test. The problem is, that it **does** work with curl but not when I submit the form in my browser.

Comment: you have forgot the comma in the form