# Express post endpoint receiving empty body

Tags: node.js, express, post, server, webhooks

**UPDATE**

It looks like the 3rd party app is sending the data with `Content-Type: text/json`. I need to figure out how to configure express middleware to accept `*/*` Content-Type

---

I am trying to expose an endpoint in Express to receive a post request (webhook notification) from a 3rd party app. Essentially, when a user clicks a button in the 3rd party app it sends a post request to the express endpoint with data.

This is what my code looks like:

```
app.use(express.json()); // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    app.post('/notify', (req, res, next) => {
        if (!req.body) {
            return res.status(400).send('Bad Request');
        }

        console.log(req.body);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
```

When I post to this endpoint with Postman **(Postman w/ payload --> My Endpoint)**, everything works and the payload is present in  `req.body` contains data.

When the 3rd party data posts to this endpoint **(3rd Party w/ payload --> My Endpoint)**, the body contains nothing and when logged it prints `{}`.

If I use an online tool like https://webhook.site to receive the data from the 3rd party **(3rd Party w/ payload --> Webhook test site**), the entire payload is present in the `req.body`.

I have no idea why it doesn't work and have tried to change the middleware multiple different times.

I have tried the following links but none worked.

[Express app empty request body with custom content type headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33489953/express-app-empty-request-body-with-custom-content-type-headers)

[Express receiving empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897059/express-receiving-empty-object)

[Node.js: Receiving empty body when submitting form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396360/node-js-receiving-empty-body-when-submitting-form).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is the 3rd party app was sending the raw json data with the content-type header as `text/plain`. I fixed the issue with:

```
app.use(express.json({ type: '*/*' }));
```